# Does $C(AB)\subset C(A) \Rightarrow rk(AB)\le rk(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does $C(AB)\subset C(A) \Rightarrow rk(AB)\le rk(A)$ ?

Trying to answer an exam question:

For $m>n$, show there are no matrices $A,B$ such that $A  $ is mxn and $B$ is nxm and $AB=I_m$

The hint in the question specifically said to use ranks

So my approach would be $C(AB)\subset C(A) \Rightarrow rk(AB)\le rk(A)$

And since $A$ is an mxn matrix, the maximum number of linearly independent columns is $n$

So $rk(AB)\le rk(A) \le n \lt m $

And as $rk(I_m)=m$, then $rk(AB)\ne rk(I_m) \Rightarrow AB \ne Im$

Does this work?

Edit:

To clarify $C(A)$ is the column space i.e. $C(A)= \{y\ | Ax=y $ for some x $\}$ = Span $\{Ae_i|\ 1 \le i \le n\}     $

Comment: What's $\;C(A)\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio It probably is the vector space spanned by the columns of $A$.

Comment: Sorry yes should have clarified that! I mean the column space which is the vector space spanned by the columns

Comment: In your statement of the question, don't you mean that $n<m$?

Answer (score 2):

Of course!

$rk(AB)= dimC(AB)$, and $rk(A)=dim C(A)$. So the inequality you mentioned trivially holds.